# Issue with only applying key addition layer before first round of AES

Tags: aes

What would be the issue if AES only applied the key addition layer once, before the first round? As in, how would this make the algorithm vulnerable to attack?

Comment: since the rest of the cipher now becomes an unkeyed nonlinear permutation, anyone can just reverse it, and the cipher now has the security of an XOR cipher

Comment: @RichieFrame how can you reverse a ciphertext from AES?

Comment: with only an initial key addition, with a single known plaintext block

Comment: What about the sub-bytes? Did you delete it, too?

Comment: @kelalaka no, just key addition layer once at the very beginning, rest is the same

Comment: @RichieFrame I saw you commented on another post about reversing the diffusion layers. Did you mean by this for all the rounds and then XOR with plaintext to get key? I am still lost and have not figured out the key